# Accessing an MS access db from multiple WAN locations

Tags: windows, network-share

I'm after some ideas on how best to provide a solution that one of my customers requires.

They have a legacy system which they use as a type of Customer Relationship Manager. 
Its essentially an MS Access 2000 db with a form frontend.

The DB is stored on a server and I need to provide a means for multiple users to access and work on the database simultaneously.

There is a potential issue in that this client has low bandwidth availability, so I need to minimise the amount of traffic to mitigate this.

I was going to look at sharing the db directory and mapping it on the users machines using CIFS and configure offline file sharing, but i'm not at all convinced that when various machines sync the file that they wont simply overwrite each other, so I'm back at square one.

Comment: Is "redo it using a proper database server" a solution? Whoever made that back in 2000 already was ignoring the reality of MS access in a distributed environment, and the last years have not really changed that. Time to get rid of this legacy solution - or live with the decisions made back then. Get it reworked - a web application comes to my mind.

Comment: What TomTom said, alas.  You might be able to upsize the data portion to SQL Server and use the form front end to connect via ODBC, but it would be more graceful to get someone to convert it to a web app instead.